# Using HTML POST to upload file via PHP

Tags: php, html, post, methods

I am trying to upload a local file to webserver using HTML POST method and PHP. 
this is my php code:

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$updir = "/var/tmp/";
$upfile = $updir.basename($_FILES['rawexcel']['name']);

if(is_uploaded_file ($_FILES ["rawexcel"]["tmp_name"]))
{
move_uploaded_file ($_FILES["rawexcel"]["tmp_name"], $upfile);

} else {echo "error uploading file ".$upfile;}
} else {echo "not isset post method";}
?>
```

and HTML code is:

```
<div class="container" id="upl">
<h4> Upload files</h4>
<form action="upl.php" enctype="mutipart/form-data" method="post">
<p> upload your files to DB</p>
<p><input type="file" name="rawexcel" id ="rawexcel"> 
<input type ="submit" value="Upload" name ="submit"></p>
</form>
</div>
```

$_FILES["rawexcel"]["error"] shows 0 and from running this peice of code i get

```
error uploading file /var/tmp
```

I guess file name was not retrieved from html?

Comment: What error you are getting...?

Comment: Updated question. In short - cant get filename, $upfile is only $updir

Comment: upvotes on a typo? *wow*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is in enctype:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

not:

```
enctype="mutipart/form-data"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typo mistake in  *enctype="multipart/form-data"* , instead of this you typed *enctype="**mutipart**/form-data"* . So "**mutipart**" spelling is need to correct.